# How to disable auto-spacing of * after a type in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-community

When I want to type something like

```
Type* name;
```

at some point during typing the line (as soon as I type the semicolon), VS2017 decides to auto-space to

```
Type * name;
```

After I removed the space the first time, the IDE didn't try that again for some time. The behaviour started again for some reason when I typed a type-pointer variable, but immediately typing another line like that didn't repeat the auto spacing...

After some more testing, the auto-spacing only seems to happen in a class where the first line of code after an access specifier becomes the victim if it matches `Type* name;`.

```
class Foo {
private:
    Type* name; //Becomes Type * name; after typing the ';'
public:
    Type2* name2; //Here as well
};
```

I don't like it. How do I end this blasphemy?

Comment: It's one of the code formatting options

Comment: Not to mention it is dangerous! `int* i, j` is really a pointer and an int, whereas `int *i, *j` is two pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Tools->Options, then Text Editor-C>/C++->Formatting->Spacing and look through the options, however I do not believe that particular item is configurable.

Comment: As a last resort there is an option "Automatically format statement when I type a ;" that can be turned off.

Comment: It is configurable... at least the answer I got works.

Answer (score 5):

**On Visual Studio 2019:**
*Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Formatting > Spacing*

Here change the **"Pointer/reference alignment"**
Select the option of your choice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In *Tools>Options...>TextEditor>C++>Formatting>Spacing>Spacing for operators>Binary operators* change ticked radio button from **Insert spaces before and after binary operators** to **Don't change spaces around binary operators**.